# nonnull compare error for pointer to reference when updating gcc

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing

I am updating my gcc from 4 to 10 to compile a code written with Qt and I get the following error:
 `nonnull argument 'context' comapred to NULL [-Werror=nonnull-comapre]`
The code is as follows:

```
bool report(const Context &context) {
 Q_ASSERT(&context)
 ...
}
```

This question is similar to the [nonnull-compare warning for pointer to reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550320/nonnull-compare-warning-for-pointer-to-reference) but the writer did not say why the compiler says this error.

Comment: `-Werror` options means that the compiler treats all warnings as errors. And, indeed, `Q_ASSERT(&context)` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why ```Q_ASSERT(&context)``` does not make sense? I would like to check if it is null or not?

Comment: `&context` can't be null; it is the location of an existing object. Thus, checking is pointless.

Comment: The only way for `&context` to be a null pointer is if the code that calls this function dereferenced a null pointer. That's not allowed; the behavior of the program is undefined. `const context *ptr = nullptr; report(*context);`. Don't do that.